# How to vectorize a for loop operation that involves type() function in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, integer, vectorization

I have a df with 1.500.000 rows and one row, RUT, has different types of elements str and float. I need keep all the data in int and str, because if it is float, when I coerce the element to str it generates an extra 0, i.e.,

```
# consolidado['RUT'].iloc[i] is for example 24555465, but is float type so:

str(consolidado['RUT'].iloc[i])

# it returns '24555465.0'
```

In order to coerce every float type to int I coded the following for loop

```
consolidado = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 1.1, 1, 2, 3, 45, '6k', 8],
                            'RUT': [7, 5, 3, 4.5, 54, 7, '8k', 6]})
for i in tqdm(range(len(consolidado))):
    if type(consolidado.RUT.iloc[i])==float:
        consolidado.RUT.iloc[i]=int(consolidado.RUT.iloc[i])
    else:
        consolidado.RUT.iloc[i]=consolidado.RUT.iloc[i]
```

The problem with this is that it takes a lot of time to run over the 1.500.000 observations.

Someone knows how to do it more efficient?

Comment: `consolidado['RUT'] = pd.to_numeric(consolidado['RUT']).astype(int)`

Comment: @QuangHoang I have just edit the question in the column RUT  to be more specific, because my problem is that I have float and strings, so I can't use astype() method

Comment: @MARIOANTONIOCASTILLOMACHUCA if you have a column of mixed float and int types, i.e. dtype=object, then I wouldn't worry too much about vectorization.

Comment: Note, if you *are* going to do something like this, *don't use `.iloc[i]`*, use `.iat[i]`. Indeed, replacing all the `iloc` with `iat` should significantly speed this up

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have a mix of strings and float

Comment: @MARIOANTONIOCASTILLOMACHUCA ok, again, if you are going to do that, you've already surrendered a lot of the speed advantages of pandas anyway. `object` dtypes are bad

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you really help me with iat in place of iloc, thanks!

Comment: @MARIOANTONIOCASTILLOMACHUCA out of curiosity, what was the timing difference?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I waited the loop with iloc almost half an hour (it didn't finish) and ita worked in a couple of minutes